# TypeError: market.FileViewed is not a function while trying to watch event

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, react

I want to watch for fileViewed event and it throws `TypeError: market.FileViewed is not a function` in

```
marketplace.FileViewed{
           ^
```

My solidity contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Marketplace {
    string public name;
    address owner;
    uint public fileCount = 0;
    mapping(uint => File) public files; 


    struct File
    {
        uint id;
        string name;
        address owner;
        address sharedWith;
    }

    mapping(uint => Product) public products;

    struct Product {
        uint id;
        string name;
        address owner;
        address sharedWith;
    }

    event ProductCreated(
        uint id,
        string name,
        address owner,
        address sharedWith
    );

    event FileViewed(
        uint id,
        string name,
        address owner,
        address sharedWith
    );


    constructor() public {
        name = "File Sharing System";
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner()
    {
        require(owner==msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    function addFile(string memory _name, address _address) onlyOwner public
    {
        fileCount++;
        products[fileCount] = Product(fileCount,_name,owner,_address);
        emit ProductCreated(fileCount, _name, owner, _address);
    }

    function viewFile(uint _id) public view
    {
        Product memory _file = products[_id];
        require(msg.sender==_file.sharedWith,"Not shared with you!!");
        emit FileViewed(fileCount, _name, owner, _address);
    }

}
```

This is my js:

```
marketplace.FileViewed(
    function(){
      if(this.state.account!=results.args.sharedWith)
      {
        window.alert("File not shared with you")
      }
      else
      {
        window.alert("File viewed")
      }
    })

  viewFile(id)
  {
    this.setState({loading: true})
    this.state.marketplace.methods.viewFile(id).send({from: this.state.account })
     .once('receipt', (receipt) => {
        this.setState({loading: false})
     })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileViewed` is an event if you are using web3 v1.2 you have to use like this:

```
marketplace.events.FileViewed({
    fromBlock: 0
}, function (error, event) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
    } else {
        console.log("File viewed: ", event);
    }
})
```

For more details see this: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events

Comment: Even after this, the program is not printing anything and now the error is gone though, thanks for that. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Also please upvote the question, if you think this was a valid question. Thanks

Comment: @vteja711 I'd check if your contract is generating the event. In any case probably is better to create a separate question. A few thing to verify: How do you connect to the network? Are other events being generated?

Comment: I am using ganache as my local network and metamask for my connections and interactions

Comment: @vteja711 The problem is that ´viewFile´ is marked as ´view´. That implies no transaction will be created when it is invoked. So no events are being generated. Then compiler should throw an error when using an event inside a view function.

Comment: That I have rectified but still there is no event being thrown by my contract method. That's the problem!!! Sorry that I haven't updated it here.

Comment: @vteja711 It is better to ask a new question.

Comment: I have created another please check that out and we'll carry out our discussion there https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76915/ganache-is-not-showing-any-events